# Expressing rotation where bits are represented in array

Tags: c++, binary

I've got a series of bits, represented by pointers.

```
Bit* bits[32];
```

Now I need to implement the binary right rotate operator. I've got that the first part is a right shift of the same amount, which deals with all the bits which did not wrap around, but I'm not sure what to do about the ones which do wrap around.

How can I determine which bits end up in which positions in the end results?

So far, I've got

```
ExpressionHolder rotate(unsigned int other) const {
    ExpressionHolder out;
    out.e = new Expression;
    for(int i = 0; i < (32 - other); i++) {
        out.e->bits[i] = e->bits[i + other];
    }  
    for(int i = (32 - other); i < 32; i++) {
        out.e->bits[i] = e->bits[31 - i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: You continue to surprise me with the occasional question that I'm sure you could have figured out yourself.  Just feeling lazy today?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I distrust any intuition where the type system won't catch a mistake and I won't even find out if there is a mistake until I depend upon the results. I behave the same way with algorithms on `float` - no matter what shit you write, you always get a `float` back out and if the answer isn't what it should be, good luck working out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum mechanics dictates that bits are always in a superposition of one and zero. So we can never be sure of the actual bit value of your pointer until we look at *e.bits[i].

But then after we look a straightforward

```
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
     out.e->bits[i] = e->bits[(i + other) %32];
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Nice QM reference, but `bits[i]` only represents a bit. It is not an actual bit and does not have a defined value.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::rotate_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate_copy) should do the trick

```
ExpressionHolder rotate( ExpressionHolder const& in, std::size_t count )
{
  ExpressionHolder out;
  out.e = new Expression();

  std::rotate_copy( in.e->bit, in.e->bit + 32 - count, in.e->bit + 32, out.e->bit );
  return out;
}
```